# How can I sort an array by segments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, javascript-objects

How can I sort:

```js
[[{path:'a/b/c'}],[{path:'a/b'}],[{path:'a/b/c/d'}],[{path:'a/b'}]]
```

into this:

```js
[[{path:'a/b'}],[{path:'a/b'}],[{path:'a/b/c'}],[{path:'a/b/c/d'}]]
```

I want to sort it by segment length. For example, a/b/c is three segments.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Why do you have an extra array around each object?

Comment: Sort by `el[0].split('/').length`

Comment: Hi @vue-dev if you found my answer useful would you mind marking it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and count the length of the output array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let toSort = [[{ path: 'a/b/c' }], [{ path: 'a/b' }], [{ path: 'a/b/c/d' }], [{ path: 'a/b' }]];

toSort.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[0].path.split('/').length - b[0].path.split('/').length
});

console.log(toSort);
```